# Why local class object is not deleted after it is returned in C++?

Tags: c++

I was just looking into C++ OOP basics and actually surprised after trying this:

```
class A {
public:
    A() :i(10), j(20) { cout << "constructor " << endl; }
    A(const A &obj)
    {
        cout << "copy constructor" << endl;
    }
    int i;
    int j;
    ~A() { cout << "destructor " << endl; }
};

A func()
{
    A loc;
    cout<<&loc<<endl;
    return loc;
}

int main()
{
    A obj = func();
    cout<<&obj<<endl;
}
```

I ran the above code using **g++ (GCC) 4.8.5**

The output is:

```
constructor 10
0x71a5b3354010
0x71a5b3354010
destructor 10
```

Here,
   First,I was expecting copy constructor to be called. But it didn't (when ran with MSVC++ 14.0 it did). And how could be the local object in `main()` be the same as the object in `func()` (it gave the same object address)?

I'm just a beginner in C++ and couldn't understand that behaviour. Please clarify!!!

Comment: Is `A obj = display();` meant to be `A obj = func();`?

Comment: You never seem to call func(), so I don't see how you could have obtained the address of a local variable in it.

Comment: @juanchopanza you beat me to closing this by about 2 seconds <shakes fist> ;)

Comment: @Xirema, Corrected the question.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, You mean to say, the new object has been created in the same place as deleted object?

Comment: @infinite The compiler is optimising the use of space on the stack.

Comment: @infinite No object has been deleted - note that `delete` has a special meaning in C++.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, yeah sorry for that term!!!

Comment: @NeilButterworth, not really. Nobody cares about the use of the space on the stack. Compiler is optimizing number of constructors being called.

Comment: @SergeyA, exactly. If its about space reusing, atleast there'll be an extra constructor and destructor in prints